# How can I collect all the properties of a node in a vector in neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I know that Collect() can be used to store the values as a vector, how can I do this for the values of all the properties of a node ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how useful that will be to you, as with a values collection you lose the context of what property the value is for. I suppose if you sort it you might have some idea, provided all the nodes you do this for have the same properties, but Neo4j has no table schema to restrict properties, so I wouldn't really recommend doing this.

This example shows how you might do this:

```
match (n:Person)
with n
with n, keys(n) as keys
return [key in keys | n[key]] as values
```

EDIT

You probably already know how you're going to apply cosine similarity in Cypher, but if not, this [graphgist](https://neo4j.com/graphgist/a7c915c8-a3d6-43b9-8127-1836fecc6e2f) covers a general approach, though it's on relationships rather than node properties.

As far as your case, you'll need to make sure your ordering is consistent, so maybe  order the keys first, either by UNWINDING back to rows then doing a `WITH ... ORDER BY` then collecting again, or by using `apoc.coll.sort()' using [APOC Procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_collection_functions).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, actually I want to apply cosine similarity to find similarity score between the products (of same category), so I need all the property values in a vector. The values are binary and yes all the nodes have same properties. I know, i have been using RDBMS concept here to make my life easier but I cant seem to find a better alternative that completely uses graph concepts only to implement content based filtering algo using cosine similarity method. I would be in a debt if you could guide me to do it the right way.

Comment: Yes I have seen that graphgist that implements collaborative filtering using cosine similarity and works on relationships. My case is slightly different, since I am new to cypher, I am struggling at this point. For now, If I do the ordering thing and then collect all the values in a vector, how can I still make sure that properties of all the nodes get stored separately into separate vectors ? Also after that how can I loop into getting consecutive values of one vector multiplied with the corresponding values of 2nd vector and so on with all other vectors?